# What options do I have if I got far fewer airline points than what I was promised on chat at time on booking?

Tags: usa, air-travel, bookings, airlines, delta-air-lines

I had a ticket on Delta. I chose that miles be credited to my JPMiles account. I specifically asked the Delta chat agent how many JPMiles I would earn. He told me that I would earn around 19,744 JPMiles per passenger for the return trip (I have the chat transcript).

After completing the onward journey only 600 miles were credited. When asked, Delta told me to wait until the trip is completed (transcript available). Today, more than 6 months after the return trip, only 1,800 miles have been credited. I have lodged another complaint but Delta responds very slowly and I doubt that they will do anything.

What are my options?

I live in India and it was an India-USA return trip.

Update - I called SkyMiles and explained to them that I had already sent a mail with all the proof. After much persuasion they gave me two options.

1. $300 travel vouchers each valid for one year.
2. 20000 SkyMiles in each travelers account.

I choose the second option. 
Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: You might want to check the Jet Privilege [mileage calculator](https://www.jetprivilege.com/use-jpmiles/mileage-calculator-earn-jpmiles); check the fare class on your booking confirmation to see how many miles you should have gotten. Since Delta doesn't currently fly to India, I assume at least one leg of your journey was operated by another airline. Maybe you only received miles for the Delta part of the trip? Either way, there is not much that you can do about it anymore because the window to claim missing JPMiles ends 180 days after the flight has been taken.

Comment: Why do you expect to know how many miles will be credited in another airline’s program?

Comment: Did you talk toSkyMiles or to reservations? Most frequent flyer programs are insanely complicated, especially when it comes to partnerships, and it's entirely possible that, say, a ticket agent would naively have just looked up the city pair and given you the distance without factoring the dozen other factors that go into how much credit you receive. In a very large airline like Delta, the level of sophistication among agents is considerable, for virtually any customer service matter, hence the common advice that if you don't like whta you hear, hang up and try again for a different agent.

Comment: Basically, it's worth noting that frequent flyer programs are part of the airline's marketing program, not its sales or operations. In some cases, they are literally run by separate companies altogether. So don't trust a ticket agent to tell you about mileage matters any sooner than you'd trust a baggage handler to tell you the gate you'll arrive at in your destination city or a pilot what the dinner is going to be in business class. Sure, they might know, or know who to ask, but it's not really their department.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options here, and I strongly suggest starting with the first one.

1. Reach out to Delta Skymiles with a **written** request. Provide all the evidence, such as:

   - Your chat logs with agent;
   - Evidence that you booked exactly the same itinerary and rate codes discussed, and you did so before, or shortly after chat (rules change all the time);
   - Evidence that you took those flights, and did not change your itinerary (this might affect the mileage);
   - Tell them if it is not possible to credit those miles, you agree to settle for a $200 Delta transportation voucher (or other value if JET miles are valued differently, but then you have to justify the number);
   - Mention that if your complain is not addressed within 4 weeks, you intend to file a lawsuit in a small claims court.

And send it to Skymiles support desk. From my personal experience - and I've been flying with Delta a lot - they always honored their promises. It is very likely the agent screwed it up, but since it was Delta agent, it is their fault.

2. Sue Delta in small claims court. Delta generally values their miles as $1 per 100 miles, so you have a valid claim for at least $197. If JET values their miles differently, you have to adjust the claim accordingly. From what you said it looks like an easy case to win. This is, however, extra hassle for small money, so it is only recommended to do if #1 failed.